# VSCode SSH connection drops after a couple hours

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, jupyter-notebook

Currently I am training some neural nets in a server using SSH connection in VSCode. I run using the Jupyter Notebook extension. The problem is that sometimes I need to train my neural nets for days, and the SSH drops after more or less 7-8 hours, and then, my training process drops as well. When I open my laptop in the morning I see a message from VSCode asking to connect again into the server, but at this point the training is not running anymore. Is there anyway that I can keep the SSH connection running for longer? Or a way of keep my training running on the server even if the connection drops?

I tried to look for anything in the VSCode configs, but I was not to find anything useful. What I need is keep the connection running for days without dropping.

Comment: have you tries using `screen` to keep the terminals open even if the connection drops

Comment: No, but how can this be applied to vscode Jupyter-Notebook?

Comment: why do you need to run these type of long running calculations from VSC, run them from the terminal on the server in a `screen` instance